# ListView.addHeaderView(View) Crash on Api 11 and API12

Tags: android, android-listview

i have a List view that i need to add a header view to it and a footer view,

it runs perfectly on any api else 11 & 12.

this is the Log cat

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot add header view to list -- setAdapter has already been called.
11-13 11:21:13.717: E/AndroidRuntime(583): at     android.widget.ListView.addHeaderView(ListView.java:255)
11-13 11:21:13.717: E/AndroidRuntime(583): at MediaFragment.setAdapter_(MediaFragment.java:1041)
11-13 11:21:13.717: E/AndroidRuntime(583): at    MediaFragment.JsonObjectOnSuccess(MediaFragment.java:991)
11-13 11:21:13.717: E/AndroidRuntime(583): at MediaFragment.GetCache_db(MediaFragment.java:2074)
11-13 11:21:13.717: E/AndroidRuntime(583): at DataBaseAdapter$GetAsyncTask.onPostExecute(DataBaseAdapter.java:253)
11-13 11:21:13.717: E/AndroidRuntime(583): at DataBaseAdapter$GetAsyncTask.onPostExecute(DataBaseAdapter.java:1)
13 11:21:13.717: E/AndroidRuntime(583): at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:590)
 11-13 11:21:13.717: E/AndroidRuntime(583): at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:149)
  11-13 11:21:13.717: E/AndroidRuntime(583): at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:603)
 11-13 11:21:13.717: E/AndroidRuntime(583): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 11-13 11:21:13.717: E/AndroidRuntime(583): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
 11-13 11:21:13.717: E/AndroidRuntime(583): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
       11-13 11:21:13.717: E/AndroidRuntime(583): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   11-13 11:21:13.717: E/AndroidRuntime(583): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
 11-13 11:21:13.717: E/AndroidRuntime(583): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
 11-13 11:21:13.717: E/AndroidRuntime(583): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
  11-13 11:21:13.717: E/AndroidRuntime(583): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and this is my Code :

```
    listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragmentListView);

    headListView = (View) mActivity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.headlistview,listview,false);
    footerListview = (View) mActivity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.media_footer,listview,false);


    listview.addHeaderView(headListView, null, false);
    listview.addFooterView(footerListview, null, false);

    listview.setAdapter(MediaAdapter);
    MediaAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listview.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
```

Comment: do you call setadapter before setting header to listview anywhere else?

Comment: Call `listview.setAdapter(null);` before you call `addHeaderView`

Comment: No I dont call it any where else

Comment: i tried to call listview.setAdapter(null); before addHeaderView  but its not working

Comment: Did you get any Solution to this ?

Comment: No I didn't find any Solution :(

Answer (score 0):

The error says: "Cannot add header view to list -- setAdapter has already been called.". This means you need to add header before setting adapter.

Also try overriding the factory method as following. It solved my problem.

```
public void addHeaderView(@NonNull View view){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        super.addHeaderView(view);
    } else {
        try {
            if (!(view.getLayoutParams() instanceof AbsListView.LayoutParams)) {
                view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                        , ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            }
            super.addHeaderView(view);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```